# How do I convert an Enum to an Int for use in an Expression.Equals operation?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I am trying to dynamically build an expression tree in C#, which is compiled and used as the predicate for LINQ-to-SQL Where() call. The problem is that I am trying to compare an Enum (with int as its underlying type) directly against an Int, but this is failing with the error "The member MyEnumType has no supported translation to SQL".

Code:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "obj"); //input parameter - this exposes a property of the Enum type
MemberExpression enumMember = Expression.Property(param, "MyEnumProperty"); //used to get the Enum typed property from the parameter

//MISSING STEP TO CAST THE ENUM OF THE MEMBER EXPRESSION TO AN INT?

BinaryExpression binaryExpr = Expression.Equal(enumMember, Expression.Constant(1));
LambdaExpression<Func<MyClass, bool>> whereClause = Expression.Lambda(binaryExpr, param);

//when whereClause is used to filter LINQ-to-SQL results, the error is thrown
```

I'm fairly new to expression trees and I can't figure this out. I have tried using

```
Expression.Convert(enumMember, typeof(int))
```

as the first part of the BinaryExpression but this doesn't fix it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have no idea about the how to get value of enum in expression tree

Comment: After some more digging, I've decided that the problem here is with my understanding LINQ-to-SQL rather than with the Expression itself. The Enum property on my entity object isn't actually a column in the database; I think this is why it's not able to translate it to a where clause. I'm going to take a different approach but if anyone has any insights, feel free to share.

Comment: Can you provide the code for MyClass as well?  The code you currently have in the post is fairly boilerplate, not much to tell from here...

Answer (score 8):

Simply, you shouldn't have to, as long as you've told LINQ-to-SQL about the enum (rather than mapping it as an `int` and having a *separate* property in C# that does the translation). For example, the following works fine:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DomainObject));
var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "SomeProperty"),
                         Expression.Constant(YourEnumType.SomeEnum));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<DomainObject, bool>>(body, param);
var count = db.Table.Where(predicate).Count();
```

The main point is that my `SomeProperty` property is mapped in the dbml to the enum. Simply overtype the type name with the enum type (including namespace).

Likewise, you shouldn't be giving it a 1, but rather the typed enum; for example:

```
Expression.Constant(Enum.ToObject(typeof(YourEnumType), 1))
```

(if all you know is `1`)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks To Marc Gravell.   (Expression Guru !)  See Correct answer.
I made a change to an Expression Routine to cater for this scenario.
Normal properties or Enums.  Incase someone finds this helpful

```
public static Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>> GetEqualsPredicate<TPoco>(string propertyName,
                                                                          object value)
                                                                          Type fieldType )
    {     

        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TPoco), @"t");   //(tpoco t)
        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);// (tpoco t) => t.Propertyname

        var someValue = fieldType.IsEnum // get and eXpressionConstant.  Careful Enums must be reduced
                     ? Expression.Constant(Enum.ToObject(fieldType, value)) // Marc Gravell fix
                     : Expression.Constant(value, fieldType);

        var equalsExp = Expression.Equal(propertyExp,  someValue); // yes this could 1 unreadble state if embedding someValue determination

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TPoco, bool>>(equalsExp, parameterExp); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

look my friend first of all you have to modify your enum to be like that:

```
public enum myenum : int
{
item1 = 0,
item2 = 1
}
```

after that you can convert between int and that eunm by that way:

```
int x = (int) myenum.item1;
```

Comment: This answer is a clear misunderstanding of the question - the OP wants to know how to use expression trees to work with enum types.  Also - enums are naturally of type 'int' in the CLR.  This question is a high search hit for C# expressions with enums and as such this answer should be lower than the more appropriate answer from @philsoady

Comment: Not related to question

Answer (score -1):

just you must convert enum to object
you can use this :

```
Expression.Constant(Enum.ToObject(enumMember.Type, enumMember .value))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
(int) enumMember
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: "Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression' to 'int'"

Comment: Heh, Sjoerd would be correct...if *enumMember* were an actual enum and not an expression tree abstraction of one.

Comment: Not related to question